# Should I create database update function outside of amplify?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have an app that gets data from dynamodb with a lambda function. And I want to update the database periodically with another lambda function that makes a request to an external api to get data.

I created all functions with amplify-cli but I think it wasn't a good idea. And with this way I also stuck on making external request authentication because I can't upload client secret json file with the function.

Should I create the updater function outside of amplify-cli? If so, how should I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amplify is most useful when creating external resources that a front-end application will call over the public Internet.

If you need to periodically execute some logic, you probably don't need to make it publicly available. I suggest to **create a scheduled execution Lambda function, using a CloudWatch event as a periodic trigger**.

[Here's an example of how to do that](https://dev.to/jameson/nightly-github-contribution-stats-with-pygithub-and-aws-lambda-8k).

The Lambda function you write can call DynamoDB directly to query/update values.

Comment: Yes, I don't need to make it publicly available. Thanks :)